# Header file declaration in iPhone

Tags: iphone

What is the difference between them:-

Approach 1:-

```
@interface EffortView : UIView {

}    
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *homeView;    
@end
```

Approach 2:-

```
@interface EffortView : UIView {
    UIView *homeView;
}    
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *homeView;    
@end
```

I have synthesized the properties in both cases. Both of them works. I am using Xcode 4.0 on Mac 10.6.6

Please enlighten me.

Thank you All.

Comment: nice one @socialCircus..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach won't work on 32-bit Mac OS X runtimes because each property must have a corresponding instance variable. 64-bit and iOS runtimes automatically create the instance variable for you, so in that case, it is enough to use the second approach.

The bottom line is: if you are 100% sure that you won't ever target 32-bit Mac OS X systems and none of the components of your software will ever be used on that platform, you can safely omit the instance variables.

Comment: you mean that Xcode 4.0 on Mac 10.6.6 uses 64- bit runtime? Which version of Xcode and Mac have 32-bit runtimes?

Comment: No; it uses a 32-bit, a 64-bit or an iOS runtime depending on what you compile your project for. Since you are compiling your project for the iPhone, you are using the iOS runtime, hence the above code would work. If you were compiling your project for 64-bit Intel processors, you were using the 64-bit Mac OS X runtime, hence the above code would work as well. However, if you were compiling for a 32-bit Intel processor and/or targeting Mac OS X 10.4 and older system,s you would be using the 32-bit Mac OS X runtime and the above code would not work.